# EasyMarklet Rails gem: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bookmarklet

I'm trying to add a bare bones marklet to my rails app. I followed the instructions at the [repository](https://github.com/Octo-Labs/easymarklet) and followed the example for a bare bones marklet [here](http://foo-vs-baz.herokuapp.com/bare). Here is the js for my marklet (pulled straight from the example):

```
(function(){

  var protocol = 'http://'
  var host = '<%= Rails.application.config.action_controller.default_url_options[:host] %>';
  var port = '<%= Rails.application.config.action_controller.default_url_options[:port] %>';
  port = port === '' ? '' : ':' + port;
  var full_host = protocol + host + port;
  document.location = full_host + "/pages/new?url=" + encodeURIComponent(document.location)

})();
```

And my link in the view:

```
<%= link_to 'Bookmarklet', easymarklet_js('my_sample_bookmarklet.js.erb') %>
```

I'm getting this error now:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
  (in /Users/myname/Rails/sample/app/assets/javascripts/my_sample_bookmarklet.js.erb)
```

That's coming from the second or third line of my JS right? How do I fix this? My javascript skills are not very good, so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `Rails.application.config.action_controller.default_url_options` may be `nil`. Can you confirm this by checking on the console? If so you'll just need to set it in your environment files. The standard default in development is:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  # development.rb
  config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
end
```

Comment: Indeed it did return nil. Do I need to set these for the production environment as well? What does that look like?

Comment: Also I think `action_mailer` should be `action_controller` yeah?

Comment: @settheline You're right, of course. I updated the answer to use `action_controller` instead of `action_mailer`. I'm not sure about the production environment... you probably need to set those too but I'm not sure what the port would be. My experience in this is limited to Mailers and was never needed for prod.